# ASP.NET session stateid issue

Tags: asp.net

i have a load balancing application, and we have an issue where a user try to log in, he/she will then see some else's name.

during the logout process we only call "Session.Abandon();".  The article in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918 states the following:

> When you abandon a session, the session ID cookie is not removed from
>   the browser of the user. Therefore, as soon as the session has been
>   abandoned, any new requests to the same application will use the same
>   session ID but will have a new session state instance. At the same
>   time, if the user opens another application within the same DNS
>   domain, the user will not lose their session state after the Abandon
>   method is called from one application.

does anyone have a clue of why the user sees some else's name while loging in?

Edited - code:

```
public class CacheManager
{
public Contact.Contact User
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["Contact"] as Contact.Contact; }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Contact"] = value; }
}
}

header.ascx.cs

/// <summary>
/// This is the session manager
/// </summary>
public readonly CacheManager Localcache = new CacheManager();


public Login()
{
     var contact = BAL.Contact.Get(this.UserName, this.Password);
     Localcache.User = contact;
     Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}

protected void Logout_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect(Constants.HomePage);
}


header.ascx:

You are logged in as
<br />
<span class="user_desc">
<%= string.Format("{0} {1}",LocalCache.User.FirstName ,LocalCache.User.LastName)%></span>
```

Comment: Are you using InProc Session State mode? I think InProc does not work well with webfarm/network load balancing. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084729/load-balancing-in-asp-net-what-i-should-consider-while-development

Comment: in-proc session state

Answer (score 1):

when a user explicitly logs out and a new user accesses the page (assuming the browser wasn't closed), the browser still maintains the sessionId (even with `Session.Clear()` and `Session.Abandon()`).

Try to add these lines of code

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

[Link to check](http://forums.asp.net/t/1446995.aspx)

Comment: if it maintains the sessionID after logging out, then the next login on the same browser will always return the same user, am i correct?

Comment: yes it if maintains `sessionId` then next login on same browser will return same user.

Comment: but the problem is the user sees some else's name, meaning he logs in with his account but another account is being returned by the application..  i really don't understand how this could happen!?

Comment: show me your code that where you assign value to session,if you are assigning it before use then it will work fine,,show me your code.