# client session id will change automatically without ending it by user in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, sessionid

I use session base authentication in my asp.net MVC website. Any time users that already using website will be logout in short time, cause of changing session id automatically, and it make trouble for them.

How can i stop session id changing?

in this pic you can see log of an user activities.
[sql user loges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WkBT.png)

Comment: Most likely, your sessions are expiring before the users's logout ticket.  Increase the timeout of your session state - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i got the log of all events and i see that session id changed but session time still alive because i config my session time to 50min,  so after changing, user can not continue his works,and he get access deny, however original session id is still exist,but its not for current user

Comment: Are you on a web farm / using shared hosting?

Comment: Yes.I use a web farm

Comment: Ok - that explains why your session id is "randomly" changing.  By default, sessions run inside the server they were created on.  Having multiple servers means the you have to use a different method to store your session information.  Have you setup your session state so that it can be shared across the servers in the web farm such as using SQL Session State?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686873/allowing-session-in-a-web-farm-is-stateserver-good-enough

Comment: No, i used just inproc mode in session.  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="50"></sessionState>

Comment: On a web farm, `InProc` sessions are **not** shared among the servers.  You need to use something other than `InProc` such as `SqlServer Session State provider` that can be shared among your web servers.

Comment: i don't need share session among the server. i just need a session correctly work in a website in hosting (don't change session of my user periodic in 5 min, 10 min, ...). i can't find reason of this behavior.

Comment: i was add a pic of user activities log in the question. please check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem happened when in any redirect of my website, redirect between "http://www.blabla" and "http://blabla". when change user URL requested, changed his session id and ...
i modify my code and use just "http://www.blabla" in my redirects.